# Timeout embedded booking form on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a third party booking service embedded in our site. The booking ability works fine on a desktop but it time-out on mobile phone, please check this [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBB1i.jpg) that shows the problem clearly. I am trying to understand why is happening

This is the simple container that has the embedded code and there is the [website](https://wivohealth.com/book-test)

```
                <div class="iframe-container">
                    <iframe 
                        loading="lazy" 
                        src="https://wivo.myaestheticrecord.com/book/appointments/bBQyDNe8pm7oPzox9jGXORxW6aK54J/clinics">
                    </iframe>
                </div>
```

Anyone can maybe point me in the right direction of why this issue might be happening or a way to debug this since I don't know of a way to examine these things on phones

Comment: Would it be possible to edit your code so that it is a runnable snippet?

Comment: I can't edit the code from `myaestheticrecord.com` It's a medical CRM website and they are unwilling to help. but the link itself `https://wivo.myaestheticrecord.com/book/appointments/bBQyDNe8pm7oPzox9jGXORxW6aK54J/clinics` works on mobile so could this be an authentication issue ?

Comment: I tried adding sandbox in the iframe box and it made the button unclickable